# В чем разница между 1fr и auto?

Tags: css3, html5, css-grid

Имеется виду в CSS Grid и когда что использовать?

Comment: А вы создайте две строки: `1fr` и  `10 vh` и в первую положите, незнаю, кнопку, а затем поменяйте `1fr` на `auto`

Comment: в строку или в колонку?

Comment: Какая разница в строку или колонку?

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог -- галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 3):

На примере свойства [grid-template-rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows):

`fr` или `fractional unit` это ***часть*** свободного пространства, соответственно `1fr` равен одной части от всего оставшегося свободно пространства, т.е это ***заданное*** значение ширины.

при варианте `auto` ширина будет зависеть от ширины контейнера и от ширины контента каждого item'a расположенного в этом ряду, т.е ***не заданное*** значение ширины.

Answer (score 1):

И `auto` и `fr` работают со свободным пространством. Если его нет, то размеры элемента будут равняться размеру его содержимого.

Когда они расположены вместе, например, `grid-template-rows: 1fr auto`, то "выигрывает" `1fr` (2 пример).

Ещё одно отличие `fr` от  `auto` заключается в том, что с помощью `fr` можно управлять сколько пространства нужно "откусить" (3 пример).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

div {
  margin: calc(2vw + 2vh);
  display: grid;
}

p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: tomato;
  grid-template-rows: 10% auto auto;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 3fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>10%</p>
  <p>auto</p>
  <p>auto</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>1fr</p>
  <p>auto</p>
  <p>auto</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>2fr</p>
  <p>3fr</p>
  <p>1fr</p>
</div>
```